# Check if textbox text was changed since form was opened

Tags: c#, textbox

Howdy
I have a form in my application which has 7 textboxes.  In the constructor of the form I run the method "MakeText()" that inserts values from a MySqlDataReader into the textboxes.

The user can change the values in those textboxes and when a "submit" button is clicked it will run an update query on the database to write all the changes made.
This is all fine, but I find it a waste of resources to be querying the database even if the user didn't change any of the text in the textboxes.

So I need some way to check if the user changed any of the values in the textboxes after the form was loaded.
I'd like to do this on the application level instead of letting the database handle it.

How can I do this?

**EDIT:** I just thought of this.  Maybe I could put all the values into class strings when the form loads and then just check against that before running the query.  Sometimes you just need to put a question into words to think of the answer :D

That's the best I could think up anyway...

Comment: I'd probably setup a class to hold a refernce to a textbox, and store it's value when it was created, then have a "HasChanged" property that compares the current text against the stored value. To be more general you could have it store a lambda expression to retrieve the value, so it will work with all controls.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could store the initial value in the .tag value of the textbox then just do a comparison between current text and the tag text

Comment: Tag is used. Other ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You can try something like this.

```
 public bool TextWasChanged = false;
 protected void form1_load()
 {
     MakeText();
     textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_TextChanged);
     textBox2.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_TextChanged);    
     ...
     ...
     ...

 }

    private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextWasChanged = true;
    }

    void UpdateDB()
    {
        if(TextWasChanged)
        {
              // Update DB
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can have a boolean flag related to each one of your text boxes and use the textchanged event of the textbox when that event is fired it means that text in the sender textbox has changed so you have to set the flag to show that text for this textbox has changed . 
*if you want yoiu can use textbox.tag instead of the mentioned flag

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((TextBox)sender).tag = "true" ; //you can set whatever you want here to show text has changed
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you could make a field

```
bool test = false;
```

and then check the TextChaged event for each TextBox..

that event setting the test = true;

then submit is pressed, check if test = true, if so update the database

Answer (score 1):

Create a class with a property for each textbox.   Within that class implement the logic needed to determine if a changes were made.

Then use databinding to attach the textboxes to an instance of your class.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a quick solution based on my comment, setup in linqpad (probably doesn't need the generic)

```
void Main()
{
    var test = new tester() { val = "123" };
    var changeTest = new ObjectHasChanged<tester>(test,t=>t.val);

    changeTest.HasChanged.Dump(); //false

    test.val = "321";

    changeTest.HasChanged.Dump(); //true
}
public class tester
{
    public string val { get; set; }
}
public class ObjectHasChanged<T>
{
    public bool HasChanged
    {
        get
        {
            return !this.initvalue.Equals(this.valueExpression(this.obj));
        }
    }
    private object initvalue {get; set;}
    private Func<T,object> valueExpression { get; set; }
    private T obj { get; set; }
    public ObjectHasChanged(T obj, Func<T,object> valueExpression)
    {
        this.obj = obj;
        this.valueExpression = valueExpression;
        this.initvalue = valueExpression(this.obj);
    }
}
```

You would say something like:

```
var MyTextBoxChangeTest = 
    new ObjectHasChanged<Textbox>(this.myTextBox,t=>t.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
private TextWatcher textWatcher;
```

In constructor after InitializeComponent():

```
var textWatcher = TextWatcher.Watch(tbProfile);
```

When filling the untouched text:

```
textWatcher.SetInitialState();
```

To check if the control's text has been changed:

```
textWatcher.IsChanged
```

**Implementation**:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class TextWatcher
{
    private Control control;
    private string initialState;

    public TextWatcher(Control control)
    {
        this.control = control;
    }

    public void SetInitialState() => initialState = control.Text;

    public bool IsChanged => initialState != control.Text;

    public static TextWatcher Watch(Control control) => new TextWatcher(control);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look:

```
Private Sub cmdTutup_Click()
   If mbEditFlag = True Then
   If MsgBox("Apakah perubahan akan disimpan ", 4 + 32 + 256, "Perhatian") = vbYes Then
     sqltxt = "update tbproduk set kduser='" & vkduser & _
     "',margin1=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 4)) & ",margin2=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 5)) & ",margin3=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 6)) & ",margin4=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 7)) & ",margin5=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 8)) & _
     ",hrgjual1=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 9)) & ",hrgjual2=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 10)) & ",hrgjual3=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 11)) & ",hrgjual4=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 12)) & ",hrgjual5=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 13)) & _
     ",discjual=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 14)) & ",qty1=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 15)) & ",qty2=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 16)) & ",qty3=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 17)) & _
     " where kdproduk='" & fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 1) & "'"
     conn.Execute sqltxt, , adCmdText
   End If
   mbEditFlag = False
  End If
  Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you answer a question please also provide an explanation, so that people (not just the asker) can learn from you. You can come back and edit this answer to make it clearer

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub cmdTutup_Click()

If mbEditFlag = True Then
  If MsgBox("Apakah perubahan akan disimpan ", 4 + 32 + 256, "Perhatian") = vbYes Then
     sqltxt = "update tbproduk set kduser='" & vkduser & _
     "',margin1=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 4)) & ",margin2=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 5)) & ",margin3=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 6)) & ",margin4=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 7)) & ",margin5=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 8)) & _
     ",hrgjual1=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 9)) & ",hrgjual2=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 10)) & ",hrgjual3=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 11)) & ",hrgjual4=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 12)) & ",hrgjual5=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 13)) & _
     ",discjual=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 14)) & ",qty1=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 15)) & ",qty2=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 16)) & ",qty3=" & Val(fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 17)) & _
     " where kdproduk='" & fgproduk.TextMatrix(brsditinggaklan, 1) & "'"
     conn.Execute sqltxt, , adCmdText
  End If
  mbEditFlag = False
 End If
 Unload Me
End Sub
```